# Which version of ffmpeg is the latest?

Tags: ffmpeg

[Here](https://github.com/BtbN/FFmpeg-Builds/releases) you can find all current versions of `ffmpeg`. I need one for `Windows x64`. I found there are multiple versions:

- `ffmpeg-master-latest-win64-gpl-shared.zip`
- `ffmpeg-master-latest-win64-gpl.zip`
- `ffmpeg-master-latest-win64-lgpl-shared.zip`
- `ffmpeg-master-latest-win64-lgpl.zip`
- `ffmpeg-n5.0-latest-win64-gpl-5.0.zip`
- `ffmpeg-n5.0-latest-win64-gpl-shared-5.0.zip`
- `ffmpeg-n5.0-latest-win64-lgpl-5.0.zip`
- `ffmpeg-n5.0-latest-win64-lgpl-shared-5.0.zip`

Which is currently the latest version? Why are there so many versions? And why does the package size differ?

My use case is converting private video data.

Comment: The lastest is "ffmpeg-master-latest-win64-gpl.zip" or "ffmpeg-master-latest-win64-lgpl.zip". the difference between the 2 is the license type, you should look into this based upon the type of use you require. You can find more information here - https://www.ffmpeg.org/legal.html#:~:text=FFmpeg%20is%20licensed%20under%20the,applies%20to%20all%20of%20FFmpeg.

Comment: Thank you @CraftyB for your comment! See my updated question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you [read the README for the repository you linked to](https://github.com/BtbN/FFmpeg-Builds/blob/master/README.md) you will see an explanation for all the different version under the header [Targets, variants and add-ins](https://github.com/BtbN/FFmpeg-Builds/blob/master/README.md#targets-variants-and-addins):

> Available:
>
> - `gpl` Includes all dependencies, even those that require full GPL instead of just LGPL.
> - `lgpl` Lacking libraries that are GPL-only. Most prominently libx264 and libx265.
> - `gpl-shared` Same as gpl, but comes with the libav* family of shared libs instead of pure static executables.
> - `lgpl-shared` Same again, but with the lgpl set of dependencies.
>
> All of those can be optionally combined with any combination of
> addins.
>
> - `4.4` to build from the 4.4 release branch instead of master.

So, for example `ffmpeg-n5.0-latest-win64-gpl-5.0.zip` is built from the `n5.0` branch and includes all dependencies, even those that require full GPL instead of just LGPL.

Unless you require a specific set of libraries / licenses I think it's easiest to just get the full [ffmpeg releasebuild](https://www.gyan.dev/ffmpeg/builds/ffmpeg-release-full.7z) for the latest release version from [gyan.dev](https://www.gyan.dev/ffmpeg/builds/#release-builds).

Comment: What does "the libav* family of shared libs instead of pure static executables" mean?

Comment: Not sure, but perhaps these pages can help you along? [Libav Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Libav) and [Difference between static and shared libraries?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2649334/1256347)